# CustomAuthorizeAttribute always fire

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my project, I've implemented my own authorize attribute as well my custom role provider and custom sql provider. those are injected by ninject.

custom sql provider and custom role provider are working good.

The problem is on my custom authorize. It always fire, even if I call an action that doesn't have the custom attribute.

Anyone as ever had the same problem?

**UPDATE**

My NinjectConttroller Class:

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new SiteServices());

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext context, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            return null;
        return (IController)kernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    private class SiteServices : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ISQLMembershipProvider>().ToConstructor(x => new SQLMemberShipProvider(ModelHelpers.SpotDBEntitiesConnectionString));
            Bind<ISQLRoleProvider>().ToConstructor(x => new SQLRoleProvider(ModelHelpers.SpotDBEntitiesConnectionString));
        }
    }

    public void InjectProvides()
    {
        kernel.Inject(System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider);
        kernel.Inject(System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider);
    }

}
```

My Global asax:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        NinjectControllerFactory controllerFactory = new NinjectControllerFactory();
        controllerFactory.InjectProvides();

        //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();


        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());

        //ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder());
        //ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new DateTimeModelBinder());
        //ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(SaftProject.Models.vmReservaRegistrationBase), new InheritanceModelBinder());
    }
```

MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
        {
            RouteData["returnUrl"] = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
            string url = urlHelper.RouteUrl(RouteData);
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(RouteData);
        }
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        UtilizadorRole userRole;
        var cacheUserRole = new Cache<UtilizadorRole>();
        if (cacheUserRole.IsValid) userRole = cacheUserRole.Data;
        else throw new TimeoutException("Sessão expirou");

        //verifica o httpcontext
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }

        System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;

        bool temRole = false;

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            temRole = false;
        }

        if (userRole.RoleID == 5 && Users.Length > 0 && !Users.Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            temRole = false;
        }

        if (userRole.RoleID == 5 && Roles.Length > 0 && !temRole)
        {
            temRole = false;
        }

        foreach (string role in Roles)
        {
            if (userRole.Role.Role1 == role)
            {
                temRole = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return temRole;
    }
```

CustomAuthorize usage:

```
    [MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute("Login", "Account", Roles = new string[] { "Financial Manager", "Accountant" })]
```

Comment: Where is your `MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute` applied? Class/method?

Comment: are apllied to actionresults